# Php form example is not working

Tags: php, webforms

I'm learning Php, reading it from a book following examples.
But something isnt working as described in the book, i dont understand why not
I have installed XAMP, and am running PHP version 5.5.9. 
register_globals has not been set as was described in the book (as i understood this is default in v 5.5.9)

There are two .php pages
The first page is called form.php, the book didnt explain where to put.
It didnt work in the root, and so i made phpforms folder and placed it there

```
<html><head><title>First HTML Form</title></head>
<body>
<table cellpadding ="15"><td bgcolor="lightblue" >
<form action="/phpforms/form.php" method="POST" >
<p> Please enter your name: <br />  <input type="text" size=80 name="your_name">
<p> Please enter your phone: <br /> <input type="text" size=80 name="your_phone">
<p>
<input type=submit value="submit"><input type=reset value="clear">
</form>
</table></body></html>
```

The seccond page is made to read the entered vaues.

```
 <HTML><Head><Tile>Show me the data</Title></Head><body>
 <?php  extract($_REQUEST, EXTR_SKIP); // Extracting the form input
        print "Welcome to PHP $your_name<br />";  
        print "Can I call you at $your_phone<br />";
 ?>
 </body></HTML>
```

When I enter data in the first page, it gives no error.
However when i then try to readout the entered data in the seccond page it doesnt work
I get two lines showing

**Notice: Undefined variable: your_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\Peter.php on line 3  ***

**Notice: Undefined variable: your_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\Peter.php on line 4  ***

Its an introduction to php forms, but well its pretty essential for going on with this book. I'm new to this could someone help me out here ?.

Comment: you should use $_POST["your_name"] you don't have the $your_name variable

Comment: wait a second, the submit button seems to be aiming at '/phpforms/form.php', how is it coming that your errors are related to 'Peter.php'?

Comment: You're missing a closing `>` in `<form action="/phpforms/form.php" method="POST"` so do `<form action="/phpforms/form.php" method="POST">`

Comment: @user219279: I've rewritten all your code, I'll post you an answer, please read it, and stay far for a second from your book.

Comment: I think you where all right the error was in the book, a wrong target page mentioned in the post command. the page to read the data was ./Peter.php and ./phpforms/form.php was used to enter data.
Briosheje, wrote a well explained article but like my book post still had /phpforms/form.php After reading Bleuhounds post the error came clear to me (although in text briosheje was correct only the example code for my files it didnt work). So who should i reward now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add quotes around the `type=""` attribute and insert a `>` at the end of the form.

It is important to understand how the `POST` method works. The `action` attribute on your first form should contain the url of the destination page. Then use

```
$name = $_POST["your_name"];
echo $name;
```

to display the information in the second page. the `$_POST` form returns an associative array so all of the keys correspond to the `name=""` attribute in the form and all of the values equal the value of the form. Be sure to use: `if (isset($_POST["your_name"]){}` to handle any exceptions as well.

Comment: The document i use for reading the data is Peter.php should i put that there instead of phpforms/form.php As form.php contains the form for entering the data

Comment: Aha this was indeed the error in the book.
I changed the Actrion attribute to with /Peter.php

And after submit it opened that page too, i now understand how it works too.

Comment: Ok well since with your note it came clear i reward you with stackexhange points. Your answer is short and to the point.
The other long answer from biobrehe, he took quite some time to write it i'd like to thank him too.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your `<form>` tag's type attribute with quotations.
`<input type=submit value="submit"><input type=reset value="clear">`
should be
`<input type="submit" value="submit"><input type=reset value="clear">`

Other than that, your code appears to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever book you are following, I would recommend you to first check some HTML basics.

In any case, I've re-written the whole code here, actually trying to be **as close close as possible to your**.

What I've done is:

1. Define a DOCTYPE foreach file (this is important, not that we
   have HTML5.
2. Syntax errors have been corrected, almost everywhere (in both scripts).
3. Tried to put some effor to make this code **a little bit more responsive**. Most of the tags you have used are deprecated, such as `cellpadding`, `bgcolor`.

What the tutorial was about is using the **extract** php function to **extract the values passed to the form into some temporary variables in order to don't have to store each variable using $_POST**, which is **clever** but you don't see that often.

First of all, check the extract() function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

What I've done, I've rewritten your main code:

It **should have any name**, in your case, it SHOULD BE **peter.php**, in the **main directory**:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>First HTML Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="background: lightblue; padding: 1%;" >
            <form action="/phpforms/form.php" method="POST" >
                <p> Please enter your name:</p> <br />  <input type="text" size=80 name="your_name">
                <p> Please enter your phone:</p> <br /> <input type="text" size=80 name="your_phone">

                <input type="submit" value="submit"><input type="reset" value="clear">
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Most important:

- THE CHARSET: Nowaday, please define a charset.
- Your table structure was completely wrong. It still doesn't have a sense either, but at least it has a **correct syntax**.
- I've corrected all the syntax error you had: First, you didn't close your `<form`, second, you didn't close any `<p>` tag with its `</p>` and third, you didn't enclose properly your submit and your reset button, but some browers still would interprete it correctly.

Now, **in order to make it work, you should have, in your C:\xampp\htdocs\ folder, a folder named *phpforms* CONTAINING A FILE CALLED form.php**. If you don't have such, your form will **never work**, because it is aiming to the **form.php script** which is located in the **/phpforms** folder. Don't forget that **you have defined that in your action parameter in the form ahead, by writing: `action="/phpforms/form.php"`**.

At this point, the **form.php** page should be structured like such:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Show me the data</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <?php  
        extract($_REQUEST, EXTR_SKIP); // Extracting the form input
        print "Welcome to PHP $your_name<br />";  
        print "Can I call you at $your_phone<br />";
     ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**How does it work?**

Using extract() on $_REQUEST will get the $_REQUEST array and **explode it in a serie of variables according to the name of the compiled form**.
Since you have named the two **inputs** in the previous form as `name="your_name"` and `name="your_phone"`, the extract() function will parse the value of the input named "your_name" in the variable **$your_name** and the value of the input named "your_phone" into the variable **$your_phone**.

Once you extracted the values, so, you can easily print them using:

```
print "Welcome to PHP $your_name<br />";  
print "Can I call you at $your_phone<br />";
```

The output, would be this:

**main page** (maybe **peter.php**?) :

[image]

Once submitted:

[image]

Comment: Well i had the form in the phpforms folder (created as a windows folder) already, rechecked it al. Thanks for your explanations.
In my book so far <p> is not closed as in  </p> but i've seen  more minor errors like that. Besides that i still got the same errors.
Then i copied your php source code, and still got the same errors

Comment: I dont know who to reward, you helped me, but my setup was different form.php was the form and Peter.php was used to read it out.
Your example contained the typo as in the book, altough you explained it in text. it was only after reading user Bleuhound post below here that i came to understand the error was POST method.

Comment: What you didn't yet understand is that the example of your book DIDN'T want you to use $_POST :)